# Javascript availability validation in PHP CodeIgniter framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

Really need help please. I can't seem to make the validations of this page work. I have a page that displays categories and everything works fine. No problem in adding and editing of records except that my validation for checking if the record already exists is not working.

View:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php

$message              = (isset($is_editing))? 'Name already exists' : 'Name available';
$mode                 = (isset($is_editing))? 'disabled' : 'disabled';
$category_name        = (isset($is_editing))? $categorycontent->category_name : NULL;
$process              = (isset($is_editing))? 'Edit' : 'Create';
$form_action          = (isset($is_editing))? 'category/update_category/' . $id : 'category/create_category';
$test  = NULL;
?>
<style type="text/css">
.check_exists
{
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
</style>
<?php echo form_open($form_action, 'id="frm" class="form-horizontal" style="margin: 0;"'); ?>
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $process ?> Item Category Information</h4>
</div>
<div class="span6" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:10px;">
  <!-- Project Content Fields -->
  <div class="control-group">
    <p class="control-label">Item Category Name*</p>
    <div class="controls">
      <?php echo form_input('category_name', $category_name, 'id="category_name" style="height: 30px;"'); ?><span id="team_verify" class="check_exists" ></span>
    <?php echo form_input('test', $test, 'id="test" style="height: 30px;"') ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--   <div class="control-group">
</div> -->
<!-- <?php echo form_hidden('creator_id', $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id); ?> -->
<!-- END Project Content Fields -->
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#category_name").keyup(function() {
        //remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading
        $("#team_verify").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn("slow");
        //check the category_name exists or not from ajax

        var name    = $("#category_name").val();
        $.ajax({
          url     : "<?=base_url()?>category/check_availability",
          data    : { category_name : name },
          type    : 'POST',
          success : function(data){
            if( data == '0' ){
                    $("#team_verify").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() {  //start fading the messagebox

                        //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                        $(this).html('This User name Already exists').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                      });
                  }else if( data == '1' ){
                    $("#team_verify").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() {  //start fading the messagebox

                        //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                        $(this).html('Category_name available to register').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1);    
                      });
                  }else{
                    alert("Some error occured! Check Console");
                  }
                }
              });
  });
}); 
</script>
```

And my
category Controller:

```
public function check_availability() {
    $category_name = $this->input->post('category_name');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_name', 'category_name', 'required|is_unique[tblitemcategories.category_name]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //user name is not availble
      echo "no";
    } else {
        //user name is available
      echo "yes";
    }
  }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I'm pretty new to creating websites, so any help is much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: does it return errors?

Comment: no errors. when i add a duplicate record it successfully adds it to the table and displays it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an associative array and put it into a json for response in your PHP

```
public function check_availability() {
    $category_name = $this->input->post('category_name');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_name', 'category_name', 'required|is_unique[tblitemcategories.category_name]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //user name is not availble, even more...
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('is_available' => false, 'reason'=>validation_errors());
    } else {
        //user name is available
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('is_available' => true);
    }

}
```

Your ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
          url     : "<?=base_url()?>category/check_availability",
          data    : { category_name : name },
          type    : 'POST',
          success : function(data){
            if( data == '0' ){ // Here
                    $("#team_verify").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() {  //start fading the messagebox

                        //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                        $(this).html('This User name Already exists').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                      });
                  }else if( data.is_available ){ // Here the json response
                    $("#team_verify").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() {  //start fading the messagebox

                        //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                        $(this).html('Category_name available to register').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1);    
                      });
                  }else{
                    alert("Some error occured! Check Console");
                    console.error(data.reason);
                  }
                }
              });
```

Also you can use a lot of useful functions, check the documentation [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#individualerrors)

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! Just had to add some missing closing Parentheses in the controller and ( data.is_available == 0). many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to change the echo statement value to 0/1 instead of no/yes.

```
public function check_availability() {
    $category_name = $this->input->post('category_name');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_name', 'category_name', 'required|is_unique[tblitemcategories.category_name]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //user name is not availble
      echo "0";
    } else {
        //user name is available
      echo "1";

}
```

Comment: i changed it to echo 1 or 0 but it still doesn't validate.

Comment: Did u check what the data returns ? Use console.log() or alert()